# Entity framework custom SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator , generate not being called

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I made a custom `SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator` to remove calculated fields from the migrations by their annotation and used `SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new TestSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator());` in the `DbMigrationsConfiguration` to set it to be used. But it doesn't seems to be being called.

Are there any other requirements to override the sqlgenerater. I'm already overriding all `generate` methods in the `SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator` and calling `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();` to see if it's being called. I also tried to remove everything in the methods but this also has no effect.

Comment: What action are you taking to trigger the generator?

Comment: I fixed it, I found out that it was being called on the update-database but not when creating a new migration.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that threw me off at first too.  Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently the `SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator` only gets called when a update-database is done. While i thought it would be used when calling de add-migration.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 10 times, I've been pulling my hair out for an hour. Doesn't appear to be [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/operations).